# PostgreSQL : how to query from 3 tables (with 1 junction table)?

Tags: sql, postgresql

table 'product'

```
------------------------------------------
| id | product_name | product_description|
------------------------------------------
| 1. | abc          | this is abc's desc |
------------------------------------------
```

Junction table 'ingredient_product'

```
------------------------------------------
| id | product_id   | ingredient_id      |
------------------------------------------
| 1  | 1            | 1                  |
| 1  | 1            | 2                  |
| 1  | 1            | 3                  |
| 1  | 1            | 4                  |
| 1  | 1            | 5                  |
| 1  | 1            | 6                  |
------------------------------------------
```

table 'ingredient'

```
------------------------
| id | ingredient_name |
------------------------
| 1  | apple           | 
| 2  | chicken         |
| 3  | beef            |
| 4  | beet            |
| 5  | oat             |
| 6  | pea fibre       |
------------------------
```

I have 3 tables and tried to query like below

```
      SELECT 
             product.name AS product_name, 
             product.description AS product_description, 
             product.created_at AS product_created, 
             ingredient.name AS ingredient_name 
      FROM 
             product 
      JOIN
             ingredient_product 
      ON 
             ingredient_product.product_id = product.id 
      JOIN 
             ingredient 
      ON 
             ingredient.id = ingredient_product.ingredient_id 
      WHERE 
             ingredient_product.product_id = 1;
```

and I get the result like below

```
{product_name: "fromm gold", product_description: "For puppies and pregnant or nursing mothers. Taste… aid digestion and salmon oil for a healthy coat.", ingredient_name: "banana"}
{product_name: "fromm gold", product_description: "For puppies and pregnant or nursing mothers. Taste… aid digestion and salmon oil for a healthy coat.", ingredient_name: "strawberry"}
{product_name: "fromm gold", product_description: "For puppies and pregnant or nursing mothers. Taste… aid digestion and salmon oil for a healthy coat.", ingredient_name: "canola oil"}
{product_name: "fromm gold", product_description: "For puppies and pregnant or nursing mothers. Taste… aid digestion and salmon oil for a healthy coat.", ingredient_name: "pilchard"}
{product_name: "fromm gold", product_description: "For puppies and pregnant or nursing mothers. Taste… aid digestion and salmon oil for a healthy coat.", ingredient_name: "ground beef"}
{product_name: "fromm gold", product_description: "For puppies and pregnant or nursing mothers. Taste… aid digestion and salmon oil for a healthy coat.", ingredient_name: "cranberry"}
```

I get the all different ingredients but wanted to show only once for the duplicates.

is there better way to query this type?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. You correctly get one record per ingredient. I cannot see any deplicate.

Comment: Sorry if my question was unclear I didn't know what word or term to use this kind of question. but finally got an answer from others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want aggregation, something like this:

```
SELECT p.name AS product_name, p.description AS product_description, 
       p.created_at AS product_created, 
       ARRAY_AGG(i.name) AS ingredient_names
FROM product p JOIN
     ingredient_product ip
     ON ip.product_id = p.id JOIN
     ingredient i
     ON i.id = ip.ingredient_id 
WHERE p.id = 1
GROUP BY p.id;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and read.
- The `WHERE` clause filters on the primary key of `product` rather than on the equivalent column in `ingredient_product`.  I think that primary keys may help the optimizer.
- This adds a `GROUP BY`, because you want one row per product.  This is aggregating by the primary key, so the `SELECT` can contain other columns.
- The `array_agg()` brings the ingredients together as an array.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply I have read what aggregate from the above link @Donat provided and It was the one I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to list the product details only once, together with a list of ingredients?

Have a look at aggregate functions e.g. there: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-aggregate.html .
I think function string_agg will help you.

Comment: Thank you I have read the doc you provided and have tried writing some and it works!

Comment: @DonKim: As it works now, would you please give me a vote?

Comment: Yes I did vote, stackoverflow alert says the vote recorded but not showing on page because my rep is so low..

Answer (score 0):

This solution casts the result of `ARRAY_AGG` to JSON, which in my use case was ideal. If you have many columns in the ingredient table, for example, JSON can be more convenient to work with.

````
   SELECT 
        product.name AS product_name, 
        product.description AS product_description, 
        product.created_at AS product_created,  
        array_to_json(ARRAY_AGG(ingredient.* )) 
        AS ingredient_names
    FROM product 
    JOIN ingredient_product
        ON ingredient_product.product_id = product.product_id 
    JOIN ingredient
        ON ingredient.ingredient_id = ingredient_product.ingredient_id 
    GROUP BY orders.order_id 
    ORDER BY orders.order_id;```
````